# Combinatorics Recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> Let $h_n$ be a number sequence where $h_n = 3h_{n-1} - 2h_{n-2}$ with $h_0 = 0$ and $h_1 = 1$. Compute the ordinary generating function of $h_n$ and then using the generating function compute a formula for $h_n$.

Does this start looks right?
We write the recurrence relation in form: 
$$h_n - 3h_{(n-1)} + 2h_{(n-2)} = 0$$

Let $g(x) = h_0 + h_1 x + h_2 x^2+\ldots$ be the generating function for sequence $h_0, h_1,\ldots$.

We have $g(x) = h_0 + h_1 x + \ldots$ as well as $-3x\,g(x) = -3h_0 x -3 h_1 x^2 - \ldots$ and  $2x^2\,g(x) = 2h_0 x^2 + 2h_1 x^3 +\ldots$.

Adding all three would give us :

$$(1 -3x + 2x^2)  g(x) = h_0 + (-3h_0 + h_1) x + (2h_0 -3h_1 + h_2) x^2 + \ldots + (h_n -3h_{n-1} + h_{n-2}) x^n + \ldots$$

Since $h_n - 3h_{n-1} + 2 h_{n-2} = 0$ and since $h_0 = 0, h_1 = 1$.

So we know that $(1 - 3x + 2x^2) g(x)= 1 + x$ and that leads to:

$$ g(x) = \frac{1+x}{(1-2x)(1-x)}.$$

Does this look like a correct start?

Comment: is this better?

Comment: Use { and } instead of ( and ) and it should be fine. (Wanted to edit, was prevented by SE). Also, before this last $g(x)$, you should put a plain English word; currently this looks like an ill-formatted math expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have:
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}h_n x^n = \frac{\color{red}{x}}{(1-2x)(1-x)} = \frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{1}$$
it is straightfoward to check that $\color{red}{h_n=2^n-1}.$

Just check your computations since the value in zero of $\frac{1+x}{(1-2x)(1-x)}$ is one, while you have $h_0=0$.

Comment: So its (1+x)/(1-2x)(1-x), which yields 1/(1-2x) - 1/(1-x) , which gives $$3(1+2x^2 + 2^2x^2....) −2(1+x+x^2....)$$ is that correct? Then we put it into summation to find the ordinary generating function.

Comment: @Chriztine: no, the generating function is given by $\frac{x}{(1-2x)(1-x)}$.

Comment: But I received $(1−3x+2x^2)g(x)=1+x$ as the result, did i make a computation mistake?

Comment: @Chriztine: yes, and I explained why.

Comment: ohhhh i see it now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. Now you need to split this expression $g(x)=\frac{1+x}{(1-2x)(1-x)}$ as a combination of simple elements, *i.e.* terms of the form $\frac{1}{a x + b}$ (in your case). From there, finishing should be easy. You may also check your answer by directly computing the terms $h_n$ as $A \lambda^n + B \mu^n$ for the characteristic roots $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Comment: Hence it becomes $3/(1-2x) - 2/(1-x)$ and it equals to $3 ( 1 + 2x  + 2^2 x^2 ....)$ and the second part equals to $-2 ( 1 + x + x^2 .... ) $ right?